# UWP APP C# - Unable to launch without Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, uwp

I have a problem with my UWP APP made for a school project.

It's a simple tasks reminder, who can be perfectly started with VS (Debug or Release mode) but when i launch it from windows, the program crashed without any informations, i just got this :
[image: Crash]

And when i try to launch in the AppX folder i have two missing DLL's : mrt100_app.dll and SharedLibrary.dll

I discovered when VS start it it's from the AppX folder, so why it tells me DLL's is missing ?

Thank you in advance...

Comment: Do you try create app package from visual studio and install app on your target?

Comment: Yes, but nothing happen when i start bin/(x86 or x64)/release/AppX/todolist.exe or i have the error in the picture.

Comment: @JeanWalrave create app package first (x86,x64 or ARM( if targeting mobile device also)) then install your package by just double clicking and install , now you can search for your installed app in start menu and launch it from there

Comment: It works ! Thank you